# what does res = disk.drv[pdrv]->disk_read(buff, sector, count) mean

Tags: c

```
res = disk.drv[pdrv]->disk_read(buff, sector, count);
```

I am not sure what the above statement means.
This is from FATFS open source driver and i am trying to udnerstand how it works. I am using STM32 SPI interface.

Comment: without any context it does not mean anything.

Comment: I see a structure member, array, indirect structure member, function, and arguments. For which part in particular do you want to know how it works?

Comment: DRESULT disk_read(BYTE pdrv, BYTE *buff, DWORD sector, UINT count)
{
  DRESULT res;
 
  res = disk.drv[pdrv]->disk_read(buff, sector, count);
  return res;
}
This is the rest of the code for that function, what i don't understand is how is this function calling itself?

Answer (score 2):

Your learning experience might be greater if you ask a question about which specific part of this confuses you... but lets break it down:

`disk.drv` means "get the member (a pointer that points into an array, in this case) that corresponds to the `drv` member of `disk`".

`disk.drv[pdrv]` means "get the element of that array indexed by `pdrv`".

`disk.drv[pdrv]->disk_read` means "get the member (a function pointer) that corresponds to the `disk_read` of `disk.drv[pdrv][0]`".

`disk.drv[pdrv]->disk_read(buff, sector, count);` means "call that function with `buff`, `sector` and `count` as arguments".

`res = disk.drv[pdrv]->disk_read(buff, sector, count);` means "assign the return value of that function call to `res`".

It seems as though the aim of the whole statement is to read a chunk of data from a drive.

Any questions?

Comment: Inferring *backwards* from the function call: `disk` is a structure - the current drive type? - that contains an list of drivers, which contains a list of functions per each driver. ..Right?

Comment: @Jongware `disk` is indeed a structure, though I assume it represents a set of multiple drives, rather than a singleton... A 'dynamic array', if you will, where `disk.drv_count` (or something like that) denotes the size of the array and `disk.drv[x]` denotes element `x`.

Comment: I'm trying to grok where that list-of-functions resides - seems I'm as lost as the OP is :) Context *is* king here.

Comment: [Link to `disk` declaration](https://github.com/iabdalkader/openmv/blob/92ded74fd96dad5a296c5e399b3e3f6cf06e545a/src/fatfs/src/diskio.c#L45)... [Link to typeof `disk` declaration](https://github.com/iabdalkader/openmv/blob/92ded74fd96dad5a296c5e399b3e3f6cf06e545a/src/fatfs/include/ff_gen_drv.h#L62)...

Comment: [Link to `disk.drv` declaration](https://github.com/iabdalkader/openmv/blob/92ded74fd96dad5a296c5e399b3e3f6cf06e545a/src/fatfs/include/ff_gen_drv.h#L64)... [Link to typeof `disk.drv` declaration](https://github.com/iabdalkader/openmv/blob/92ded74fd96dad5a296c5e399b3e3f6cf06e545a/src/fatfs/include/ff_gen_drv.h#L45)...

Comment: [Link to `disk.drv[x]->disk_read` declaration](https://github.com/iabdalkader/openmv/blob/92ded74fd96dad5a296c5e399b3e3f6cf06e545a/src/fatfs/include/ff_gen_drv.h#L49)... Hope that's helpful, @Jongware